# What exactly is קאתי in אימתי קאתי מר?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

The phrase אימתי קאתי מר in the [Chassidic song](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A8) is usually translated "When will the Master come?"

How exactly is the form קאתי derived? If I understand correctly, it must be a verbal form (whether Hebrew or Aramaic) but it does not seem to look like one. Can anyone please clarify what its root, binyan, tense, person / gender / number are? How is it vocalized? Does this word occur elsewhere in the mekorot or have any cognates, or any story behind it?

Note: it may well be that this question is off-topic for Mi Yodeya; apologies in this case - I could not find a better forum to ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Aramaic. It's the masculine singular active participle (and thus present tense) in *binyan p'al* of the root אתא, thus "comes", but compounded with the preceding word קא, [which seems to make it progressive](/a/17320): thus, "is coming".